# Are indexStats supported on ELASTIC DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, indexing, aws-documentdb

I am very new to documentDB, I have created some indexes on our ELASTIC DocumentDB and I want to run the indexStats on a collection. Looks like they're not supported as I get this error:

"message" : "Aggregation stage not supported: '$indexStats'"

It works fine with not Elastic DocumentDB. I also want to understand in the absence of indexStats, what are the other ways to make sure right indexes are getting used on the elastic DocumentDB

Answer (score 0):

According to this AWS documentation, DocumentDB Elastic clusters do in fact support the `$indexStats` stage operator: [Supported MongoDB APIs, Operations, and Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline-stage) (see "Stage Operators" section).